# How to edit rolling function for panda to look at not sliding windows but sequential windows

Tags: pandas, function, for-loop, rolling-computation

I have the data set below as in the link picture. How to use rolling function rolling( window =  offset ???  ,  min_periods  = 1, center = True, closed = 'both' ) on the windows with size of 6, going one after another ( it are not sliding windows, but sequential windows with offset of 6)

[Scheme of the windows I try to check some rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pncN3.png)

Regards,
Nataliya

Comment: Do you mean `df.groupby(df.index // 6)`?

Comment: More generlly `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 6)`

Comment: No, I mean how to change parameters of rolling function to use it for consequent windows with size 6, not for sliding windows. I don’t need to group by   dataset by 6

Comment: "on the windows with size of 6, going one after another", this is groupby 6.  `rolling` is for sliding window.

Comment: Thank you.  I  need to look at windows with size 6 for data with column category TYPE, so for one TYPE  I look at windows with len 6, then for other TYPE  I look at windows with len 6. How to group data correctly? df.groupby( TYPE, df.index//6) ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass array to `groupby`.  `df.groupby([df.TYPE, df.index // 6])`.  If this doesn't solve your issue, please update/recreate your question with sample and expected output in plain text.